# Flutter Nested Object (Basics)

Tags: flutter, class, object, nested

Below is an attempted nested object.

```
class AppColors {
  static const light = {
    final backgroundSolid = const Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 1);
    final backgroundPrimary = const Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 0.84);
  },
  static const dark = {
      final backgroundSolid = const Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 1);
      final backgroundPrimary = const Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 2550 0.84);
  }
}
```

The error is on the use of final on the first line item. What is the correct way of creating nested objects?

Comment: Hmm, do you come from JS, in which you nest object using {}?, that is equivalent to the Set data structure in Dart. Also what API/design do you want to achieve by nesting these values? Don't mind the downvote and please do ask away any doubt that you have. That's what SO is for.

Comment: Yes I would have found this very straightforward in JS. The purpose is that I can use this class as an effective data set of colors whereby I can call colors relative to theme data. Updated the question to show more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dart is a pretty flexible language, there is not really a `correct` way

You could certainly implement it using Maps, but you would lose the autocomplete and safety that a class has:

```
class AppColors {
//These are maps, note the `:` to separate key and values
  static const light = {
  'backgroundSolid' : const Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 1);
   'backgroundPrimary' : const Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 0.84);
};
static const dark = {
 'backgroundSolid' : const Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 1);
'backgroundPrimary' : const Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 2550 0.84);
};
}

void main()
{
final  backgroundLight=AppColors.light['backgroundPrimary'];

}
```

However this is how I would code it. This way you have a class holding the attributes you need, if more are added, the dart analyzer will make you refactor the factory constructors to add/delete new fields. And the access to the properties feels quite clean too.

```
class AppColors {
  final Color backgroundSolid;
  final Color backgroundPrimary;

  AppColors({required this.backgroundSolid, required this.backgroundPrimary});

  factory AppColors.light()=>
      AppColors(backgroundSolid: const Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 1),
          backgroundPrimary: const Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 0.84));
  factory AppColors.dark()=>
      AppColors(backgroundSolid: const Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 1),
          backgroundPrimary: const Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.84));

}

void main()
{
final  backgroundLight=AppColors.light().backgroundPrimary;

}
```

Comment: I implemented almost exactly this earlier today. The only difference is that I placed that I turned it around so that backgroundSolid came first and light or dark were placed in a map. This allowed me to avoid ternary operators in the main app and pass the themeMode (ie. light or dark) to App Colors. So in app I have AppColors.backgroundSolid[themeMode] where theme mode is light or dark. Thanks very much for your help, R

Comment: Glad you figured it out, and sorry for the late response.